# How to upgrade python3.2 to python3.5 on ubuntu12.04 with apt-get

Tags: 12.04, apt, python3

On My Ubuntu, `apt-get install python3` installs `python3.2`.

Even though I installed python3.5 with `apt-get install python3.5`, It just install another `python3.5` not to upgrading `python3`.
(It means there are two python version3 `python3` and `python3.5`)

At the first I remove python3(python3.2) with `apt-get --purge autoremove python3` to avoid crash between two python version3.

However, when I try to install packages having dependency for python3, Ubuntu reinstall `python3.2` even if I have `python3.5` and the package refer to `python3.2`.(for example `python3-lxml`)

How can I solve it ?

Comment: DO NOT upgrade the system's version of Python2 or Python3. It will promptly break your system. Many system services rely upon that specific version of Python2/3.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 12.04 has the latest python3 version as 3.2. I went to the subsection on python for precise (12.04) and ctrl+f for 'python3.' and found python3.2 to be the newest. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python/

Did you add a PPA? Check: `grep 'deb http' /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v 'ubuntu.com'` This would explain how it is sitting alongside your other python3 install (from the ubuntu precise source)

To solve this and prevent future headaches, either consider upgrading to Ubuntu's latest 16.04 which allows you to apt-get update && apt-get upgrade to the latest python3 (3.5) http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3.5 or use virtual environments to handle different python versions.